# How to publish the website with DevExpress in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I created an asp.net web site using `DevExpress` in `Visual studio 2013`. Now I want to publish the website in server. I copy the necessary `dll` in bin folder and delete all `DevExpress` in `web.config`. But give me below error in server:

> 500 - Internal server error.
>       There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [How to deploy ASP.NET 4.0 Web application with DevExpress DLLs?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q442045)

> Devexpress supports the standard delivery model and it is possible to
>   simply include the DLL files in the Bin folder of the distributed
>   application:
>
> [Redistribution and Deployment](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#GeneralInformation/CustomDocument3251)
>
> You can find the list of required and optional libraries for each
>   DevExpress package in the following link:
>
> [Deployment - General Information](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4834)

**Note:** you do not require to delete devexpress reference from config file if they are correct with you DevExpress version. If not then delete all references and then all correct references. Use Copy local flag to reference from the bin folder then may be it will solve your issue.

**References:**
[Setup Project Deployment of an ASP.NET Application](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113247)

Hope this help.. If it does not work then explain the issue in brief.